# mysterious network applet

Tags: wingpanel

I have a mysterious network manager applet in wingpanel:

[image]

Any idea how to remove it?

PD Already tried

> apt remove nm-applet

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

> sudo apt remove --purge network-manager*
>
> sudo apt autoremove --purge
>
> sudo apt install --no-install-recommends network-manager network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a blacklist file inside /etc/wingpanel.d/ called ayatana.blacklist and include the Package "nm-applet" inside it (without the quotes).

As reference you can look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1610627